# Null HTML5 video duration on Android Nexus 7 (HLS)

Tags: javascript, html, video

I've got my HTML5 video using HLS that works well. For my application, I need the video duration. Here's my url video. (added 'playlist.m3u8' for HLS)

```
http://server/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```

And I added a listener:

```
player.video.addEventListener('durationchange', function(){alert('Duration: ' + player.video.duration);});
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. It does work on my Ipad. But on my nexus 7, the time returned is 0. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably found out by now but Android HLS support is very limited, as such it doesn't support random access.

This means that seeking is disabled, which explains why duration is always 0.

Comment: Yes, I did find out but thank you. :) This is the correct answer!